# button to open a swf in AS 3.0

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I have been trying to find the appropriate code for this during hours. But none of the ones I found seem to work. I really need help with it...I am desperate...
I have 2 swf files. I added a button to the end of the 1st swf file (the next button).I want to go to the 2nd swf file when pressing this button. I know how to do it with actionscript 2.0 (LoadMovie)...but I started my swf in actionscript 3.0 and now ...I need to code that in AS 3.0. 
Could anybody help me with this code?? I tried with some of the codes i have seen from other users, but i don't know what i am doing wrong that any of them work for me !!

Thank you very much!

Comment: Learn how to use google: http://www.ilike2flash.com/2009/11/load-external-swf-in-as3.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help:

```
    // Set the URL of the second movie
var url:String = "url_of_your_second_movie"

// Create the loader object using the specified URL
var loader:Loader=new Loader();
var request:URLRequest;
request= new URLRequest(url);   

// Set the COMPLETE event handler  
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete );  

// Start the load
loader.load( request );

// Fill the COMPLETE event handler as needed
private function onComplete(e:Event):void
{
    // Add the loaded content to the display list
    addChild(e.currentTarget.content);
    // Do whatever else is needed once the movie is completed
}
```

Comment: Cool. Thanks for the help. both options worked, the code you posted me and the website recomended.